# Not able to run nmake on windows for CURA, link given on the body

Tags: windows, cmake, build, dependencies, nmake

I am trying to build the [source of CURA](https://github.com/Ultimaker/Cura/wiki/Running-Cura-from-Source-on-Windows). I followed the instructions but got error as below:

```
D:\work\cura-build-environment-master\build>nmake -f ALL_BUILD.vcxproj

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.00.24210.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

ALL_BUILD.vcxproj(1) : fatal error U1036: syntax error : too many names to left of '='
Stop.
```

Comment: I haven't find in the reference where it suggests to run `nmake -f ALL_BUILD.vcxproj` which attempts to interpret Visual Studio project (`.vcxproj`) as a Makefile.

Answer (score 1):

I have used CMAKE application and since Visual Studio was installed, it make files with extension of .vcxproj instead of makefiles. So I have used this command:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=../install_dir -DBUILD_STATIC=ON -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -G "NMake Makefiles" ..
```

from terminal in build folder and it worked. I created makefile for nmake.

Then nmake worked.